# Unzipping(extracting zip)file showing error,unexpected end of archive

Tags: java, zip, unzip

Here i have Bookfolder in that few more folders(english,hindi,japanese).Converting english,hindi,japanese to english.zip,hindi.zip and japanese.zip.Everything is working fine and i'm keeping zip files and folders inside Bookfolder,this thing i'm doing using with java.But when i'm unzipping manually the zip file ex:english.zip ,right click on that extract here then showing error as UNEXPECTED END OF ARCHIVE.This is my code.

```
public void foldertToZip(File zipDeleteFile) {
    //System.out.println(zipDeleteFile);
    File directoryToZip = zipDeleteFile;
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    //System.out.println("---Getting references to all files in: " + directoryToZip.getCanonicalPath());
    getAllFiles(directoryToZip, fileList);
    //System.out.println("---Creating zip file");
    writeZipFile(directoryToZip, fileList);
    //System.out.println("---Done");
}

public static void getAllFiles(File dir, List<File> fileList) {
    try {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            fileList.add(file);
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("directory:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                getAllFiles(file, fileList);
            } else {
                System.out.println("file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

public static void writeZipFile(File directoryToZip, List<File> fileList) {
    try {
        //try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(directoryToZip.getName() + ".zip"); ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)) {
        File path = directoryToZip.getParentFile();
        File zipFile = new File(path, directoryToZip.getName() + ".zip");
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile)) {
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            for (File file : fileList) {
                if (!file.isDirectory()) { // we only zip files, not directories
                    addToZip(directoryToZip, file,zos);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}

public static void addToZip(File directoryToZip, File file, ZipOutputStream zos) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        String zipFilePath = file.getCanonicalPath().substring(directoryToZip.getCanonicalPath().length() + 1,
                file.getCanonicalPath().length());
        System.out.println("Writing '" + zipFilePath + "' to zip file");
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(zipFilePath);
        zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
            zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
        }
        zos.closeEntry();
    }
}`
```

while i'm extracting new zip file(eg:english.zip) it showing error as unexpected end of archieve (i think not zipping exactly)'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to close `ZipOutputStream` in `writeZipFile()` method;

```
for (File file : fileList) {
    if (!file.isDirectory()) { // we only zip files, not directories
        addToZip(directoryToZip, file,zos);
    }
}
//here close zos
zos.close();
```

Comment: Sorry@suninsky,i tried it but its not working,showing error as:the archieve is either in unknown format or damaged.

Comment: Really? it works for me with your code. I can zip and can extract it again.

Comment: Sorry,working fine,but its zipping files only inside folder,i need all data has to be visible inside.

Comment: Now can zip and extract it back, right? That will be your new requirement :D

Comment: I mean if data is there inside folder(english)as sub1 as folder,sub2 as folder,file3 as file,file4 as file ,while zipping of english folder its making zip file only by taking files.But i need sub1,sub2,file3,file4 inside newly created english.zip file.

Comment: while making zip file its taking only files not folders,to take all inside data ,where should i change the code.please help me.

Comment: You means all (folder & files) in root level of archive file or as existing as in original folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54975/discussion-between-thaz-ahammad-and-suninsky).

Answer (score 0):

I was missing media type on ResponseEntity object and therefore I got this error information during extracting zip archive.

That means when calling rest api to download zip archive with files then needed information needs to be passed within ResponseEntity (media type application/zip, header info, cache info, etc.).

**Another observation**
is that I was missing correct return response type from angular side. There must be responseType as blob and not as text. That caused me the main issue.

```
Angular side:

getZIPData(id: number) {
   const path = resolveBase() + 'rest-api-path' + id
   return this._http.get(path, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

It might help somebody.